# Problems with calculating gcskews using python

Tags: python, function, bioinformatics

everyone.

I have some problems with calculating gcskews in python.
My 2 major inputs are fasta file and bed file.
Bed file has columns of gn(0), gene_type(1), gene name(2), chromosome(3), strand(4), num(5), start(6).(These numbers are index numbers in python.) Then I am trying to use some functions which can calculate gcskews of sense and antisense strand from the start site of each gene. The window is 100bp and these are the functions.

```
import re
import sys
import os

# opening bed file
content= []
with open("gene_info.full.tsv") as new : 
 for line in new :
     content.append(line.strip().split())
content = content[1:]       

def fasta2dict(fil):
     dic = {}
     scaf = ''
     seq = []
     for line in open(fil):
         if line.startswith(">") and scaf == '':
             scaf = line.split(' ')[0].lstrip(">").replace("\n", "")
         elif line.startswith(">") and scaf != '':
             dic[scaf] = ''.join(seq)
             scaf = line.split(' ')[0].lstrip(">").replace("\n", "")
             seq = []
         else:
             seq.append(line.rstrip())
     dic[scaf] = ''.join(seq)
     return dic

dic_file = fasta2dict("full.fa")

# functions for gc skew
def GC_skew_up(strand, loc, seq, window = 100) : # need -1 for index
  values_up = []
  loc = loc - 1
  if strand == "+" :
    sp_up = seq[loc - window : loc]
    g_up = sp_up.count('G') + sp_up.count('g') 
    c_up = sp_up.count('C') + sp_up.count('c') 
    try :
        skew_up = (g_up - c_up) / float(g_up + c_up)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        skew_up = 0.0
    values_up.append(skew_up)
  elif strand == "-" :
    sp_up = seq[loc : loc + window]
    g_up = sp_up.count('G') + sp_up.count('g') 
    c_up = sp_up.count('C') + sp_up.count('c')
    try :
        skew_up = (c_up - g_up) / float(g_up + c_up)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        skew_up = 0.0
    values_up.append(skew_up)

  return values_up  

def GC_skew_dw(strand, loc, seq, window = 100) :
  values_dw = []
  loc = loc - 1
  if strand == "+" :
    sp_dw = seq[loc : loc + window]
    g_dw = sp_dw.count('G') + sp_dw.count('g') 
    c_dw = sp_dw.count('C') + sp_dw.count('c') 
    try :
        skew_dw = (g_dw - c_dw) / float(g_dw + c_dw)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        skew_dw = 0.0
    values_dw.append(skew_dw)
  elif strand == "-" :
    sp_dw = seq[loc - window : loc]
    g_dw = sp_dw.count('G') + sp_dw.count('g') 
    c_dw = sp_dw.count('C') + sp_dw.count('c')
    try :
        skew_dw = (c_dw - g_dw) / float(g_dw + c_dw)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        skew_dw = 0.0
    values_dw.append(skew_dw)   

  return values_dw
```

As I said, I want to calculate the gcskews for 100bp of strands from the start site of genes.
Therefore, I made codes that get the chromosome name from the bed file and get the sequence data from the Fasta file.
Then according to gene name and strand information, I expected that codes will find the correct start site and gcskew for 100bp window will be calculated.
However, when I run this code, gcskew of - strand is wrong but + strand is correct. (I got correct gcskew data and I used it.)
Gcskews are different from the correct data, but I don't know what is the problem.
Could anyone tell me what is the problem of this code?
Thanks in advance!

```
window = 100
gname = []
up = []
dw = []

for match in content :
seq_chr = dic_file[str(match[3])]
if match[4] == "+" :
    strand = match[4]
    new = int(match[6])
    sen_up = GC_skew_up(strand, new, seq_chr, window = 100)
    sen_dw = GC_skew_dw(strand, new, seq_chr, window = 100)
    gname.append(match[2])
    up.append(str(sen_up[0]))
    dw.append(str(sen_dw[0]))

if match[4] == "-" :
    strand = match[4]
    new = int(match[6])
    an_up = GC_skew_up(strand, new, seq_chr, window = 100)
    an_dw = GC_skew_dw(strand, new, seq_chr, window = 100)
    gname.append(match[2])
    up.append(str(an_up[0]))
    dw.append(str(an_dw[0]))

tot = zip(gname, up, dw)
```

Comment: Using predefined bionfinformatics libraries might help (if you are open to code with things  outside the default standard library). In particular, there are fasta parsers in various libraries. I like `mappy.fastx_read` (see https://github.com/lh3/minimap2/blob/master/python/README.rst)

Comment: Maybe I missed an important detail, but it seems to me that your code does exactly the same thing in the `match[4] == "+"` and `match[4] == "-"` cases (just using different variable names, but in the end computing the same thing and storing the  results in the same lists). It is probably not what you want.